# Insertar NULL por defecto si el campo esta vació

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Tengo este campo  **Código Referencia** que se habilita según el **Tipo** de tarea que se elija cuando este se habilita permite al usuario agregar un código de referencia cuando no esta habilitado este tiene que enviar por defecto **NULL**

el código del input de código referencia tiene la etiqueta **Input**  con el atributo **Value** que tiene como valor **NULL** y el atributo **Disabled**, resulta que si tiene el atributo **Disabled**  no deja agregar campos vacíos pero si le quito el atributo **Disabled** deja mandar el campo vació

entonces como puedo hacer que cunado el usuario no necesite enviar o no elija una opción que habilite el código de referencia este lo envié NULL ¿?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Campo de bd de código de referencia** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo de campo**

```
<!---Compo para agregar el codigo de referecia de la tarea  INPUT---->
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label  title="Codigo de la tarea">Código Referencia</label>
   <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="text" value="NULL" name="codigo" class="form-control" id="selCodigos"  placeholder="Código" disabled>
      </div>
```

**código que imprime y muestra datos de la bd**

```
<table  class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action order-column ">
 <thead>
  <tr  class="headings">
    <th  class="column-title">Codigo </th>
     </tr>
      </thead>


<tbody>
 <?php 
   while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $codigo=$r['codigo'];
     ?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $codigo;?>" id="codigo<?php echo $id;?>">

<tr class="even pointer">
 <td><?php echo $codigo;?></td>
  td colspan=50><span class="pull-right">
   <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar Tarea' onclick="obtener_datos('<?php echo $id;?>');" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-udp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> 
      <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Borrar Tarea' onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id; ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> </a>
        <a title="Agregar actividad" class="btn btn-default " data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
          </span>
           </td>
             </tr>
                                  </tr>
                 <?php
                    } //end while
                ?>
```

**Código para insertar en base de datos**

```
include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

$codigo=$_POST['Codigo'];

$sql="insert into tareas (codigo) value (\"$codigo\")";
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones un **`DEFAULT NULL`** en la definición de esa columna?. Haciendo eso, y **no usándola en los `INSERT` donde no vaya a recibir datos** otorgará el valor `NULL` de forma automática. Este tipo de cosas el manejador lo hace mejor que el lenguaje de programación, así que mejor dejarla a él este «trabajo».

Comment: @A.Cedano pero cuando el usuario habilite para agregar el código de referencia como va hacer el insert del código a la bd, o no entendí muy bien

Comment: Eso es algo que pertenece a la lógica de tu programa (PHP/HTML). He entendido que querías setear *a mano*  un valor `NULL` para esa columna. Eso es mejor hacerlo por definición de tabla y cuando vaya a tener valor tomas el valor y lo insertas con normalidad. Creo que estás mezclando lo que es la lógica del programa con lo que es la definición de la tabla ¿?

Comment: En lugar de `disable` utiliza `readonly="readonly"` (disable=inhabilitar; readonly=solo lectura), igualmente como te indican, seria bueno controlar tambien si se recibe algun dato o no y actuar en consecuencia. Puedes revisar la lista de atributos aquí por ejemplo: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, señor @Xerif de hecho con el readonly funciona perfectamente pero ya no me deja habilitar  la función de javascript

Comment: esto pasa por que en el la comparación javascript tiene definido disabled

Comment: intenta poner por default el NULL en la base de datos, desde la estructura de la tabla

Answer (score 5):

Intenta chequeando con `isset()` asi:

```
$sql="insert into tareas (codigo) value (" . (isset("$codigo") ? "\"$codigo\"" : "NULL") . ")";
```